# Quebra manual de String em JAVA

Tags: java, comparação, concatenação-de-string, caracteres, jtextarea

Senhores, estou tentando fazer uma rotina que recebe um determinado texto e uma palavra do usuário, após verifica se dentro do texto existe uma palavra igual ao que foi solicitado.
Minha tentativa foi gerar um contador que verifica o caractere na posição do contador e caso não seja um espaço em branco concatena o caractere em uma string. Caso seja um espaço em branco ele verifica se o conteudo da string é igual ao texto buscado pelo usuário. Porém meu código não esta retornando um valor, como faço para corrigir.

Obs.: Pode haver novos metodos que realizem  o processo sem a necessidade de utilizar deste processo, porém meu intuito é aprender a trabalhar melhor com Strings, Caracteres e Laços de repetição.

Segue trecho do código.

```
        // Faz a separação manual de palavras e verifica .equals
    for(cont = 0; cont < texto.length(); cont++){
        a = texto.charAt(cont);
        if(!a.equals(" ")){
            montagem += a;
        } else {
            if(montagem.equals(palavraBusca)){
                palavras++;
            } else { 
                montagem = "";
            }
        }
    }
    lblResultado.setText(Integer.toString(palavras));
```

[image: Layout]

Comment: ta dando erro? retorna 0 ou valor errado?

Comment: Estava utilizando um showMessageDialog para verificar o que acontece a cada laço e aos invés de separar palavras e comparar com o digitado ele esta formando uma frase.

Comment: isso porque você só "zera" a `montagem` se encontrá-la.. alterei na resposta, vê se dá certo

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Acredito que o problema pode ser quanto ao [método `equals()`](https://www.javatpoint.com/java-string-equals); esse método compara o objeto inteiro, não apenas o valor, como é sua ideia (por exemplo, *"casa"* seria igual a *"casa"*).

Você poderia sobrescrever o método `equals()`, mas isso é meio arriscado já que outra parte do código poderia precisar do original. Sendo assim, acredito que o mais viável seria a comparação ser feita com `==`:

```
//inicialização de variáveis
montagem = "";
palavras = 0;

for(cont = 0; cont < texto.length(); cont++){
    a = texto.charAt(cont);
    
    if(!a.equals(" ")){
        montagem += a;
    } else {
        if(montagem == palavraBusca){
            palavras++;
        }

        //montagem deve ser reiniciada independente de ter sido encontrada
        montagem = "";
    }
}

//validação da última palavra do texto
if(montagem.equals(palavraBusca)){
    palavras++;
}

lblResultado.setText(Integer.toString(palavras));
```

*detalhe: não estou com compilador java, a resposta admite que seu código está correto.*

Comment: Na verdade se for um espaço em branco eu faço a verificação antes de adicionar, sendo assim ao verificar que estou em um espaço em branco o código deve quebrar independente de ser a palavra ou não, no seu código, assim que se verifica que é um espaço em branco a concatenação ja é feita. Demorou mas consegui encontrar a solução.

Comment: @GabrielGaldino.. rapaz, sinceramente não vi diferença nesse código com o que você escreveu e marcou como resposta, mas segue o baile.. =)